How to input MediaRecorder webm opus bytes to Whisper model?
I am recording voice, on the client side, using MediaRecorder, and sending the resulting blob of (webm, opus) bytes to the server using a WebSocket, with this code:
<script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {

        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=opus"});

        var socket = io();

        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
            socket.emit("message", event.data);
        });

        const latency_ms = 100; 
        mediaRecorder.start(latency_ms);
    });
</script>

I am wondering how I should process the received data on the server side to be able to input it to Whisper for transscription. I am using Flask, and the code looks something like this:
from transformers import pipeline

device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

pipe = pipeline(
  "automatic-speech-recognition",
  model="openai/whisper-small",
  chunk_length_s=30,
  device=device,
)

@socket.on("message")
def message(audio):
   prediction = pipe(audio, batch_size=8)["text"]
   print(prediction) 

